# How to deal with a player that can give it but can't take it

Tags: problem-players

So basically long story short we have an inter-party conflict where a guy has cut off a limb of another character and is meta gaming to kill two other players. Then, he got involved in the decision of a element ring, which is legendary, even though he did not involve himself in the fight and actively avoided it. This lead to an other player having to fight a dragon by themselves. Then when he made it clear he was getting involved, another player tried to shot him for 1d8 damaged to distract him. He freaked out and started to shout and hit stuff. We were going to carry on the session for another fight but this just turned everyone's moods off.  Any advice in how to deal with this player cause this isn't the first time and means our party is tip toeing around him.

Comment: Are you player or DM?

Comment: Are you talking about shouting and hitting stuff in real life?

Comment: Are you actually friends outside the game? Is this dude an abusive jerk in other situations as well?

Comment: Related - [How do I deal with a player who is a bad sport](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112658/how-to-deal-with-a-player-who-is-a-bad-sport)

Comment: Also, have you talked to this player about his behavior in the past? Also also, what is this player's experience with RPGs? new? veteran?

Comment: Details about ages would be helpful. If you're 14 and this player is 30, is different than if you're 30 and this player is 14.

Comment: What game are you playing (different games have different expectations and mechanics regarding inter-player combat and player behavior)?

Comment: Also can you clean up the language to be clear which actions are taken by the character and which are taken by the player? Specifically "He freaked out and started to shout and hit stuff."

Comment: I've voted to hold the question until the questions above can be either clarified in the post or dismissed as unnecessary. (This many querulous comments coming in so quickly indicates to me that it's not really clear what OP is getting at.) This may also be a situation where a little bit of chat may be much easier than a lot of comment back-and-forth, so I invite commenters and OP to make use of [chat] if they feel inclined.

Comment: Duplicate: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/112658/how-to-deal-with-a-player-who-is-a-bad-sport.  I am not sure the details of the exact fights in this case are relevant.

Comment: @Manuki It will be unheld if and when enough voters with hold vote privilege agree that it should be reopened. See [this help article](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) for how that works, and for a link to more information for what you can do when you disagree with a hold but don’t have hold vote privileges.